# Python: Display and count divisors of two integers

Tags: python

Write a program that will prompt the user for two integers, each of which is greater
than 0. The program will display and count the number of divisors that the two integers have in
common.
Additional requirements:
if the integer is less than 1 tell the user there is a problem and then prompt them for the
integer again.

This is what I have written so far, but I am stuck here I dont know how to incorporate both numbers. Essentially I do not know where to go from here or if 'here' is even correct???

Please help...[This is my first time with python]

```
integer1 = input("Enter an integer:  ")   
integer2 = input("Enter an integer:  ")

print integer1, ":  "  ,

i = 1
while i <= integer1 and integer2 :

    if integer1 or integer2 < 1 :
        print input("Enter an integer:  ")

    if integer1%i == 0 and integer2%i == 0 :  
        print i , 

    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do one step after the other. And try to break down your task into simple steps. In your example it could be something like:

1. Get first number
2. Get second number
3. Calculate

This you can break down futher

1. Get first number:

   - Get Number from User
   - Loop while Number is not ok

...

This way you can see that the validation should not be inside the while loop.

Another tip: test each step separately. This way you will find that `if integer1 or integer2 < 1` or `while i <= integer1 and integer2` will not work the way you think they do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how logical operators work in Python or programming in general.

```
while i <= integer1 and integer2 :
```

In Python `integer2` is a separate logical statement that is always true.
Try instead:
 `while i <= integer1 and i <= integer2`

Answer (score 0):

- You'll want to move the code that
  validates your input outside of the
  loop.
- Your `print i` doesn't need a
  comma.
- The syntax in your flow
  control needs a bit of work, for
  example `if integer1 or integer2 <
  1:` should be `if ((integer1 < 1) or
  (integer2 < 1)):`.

Answer (score 0):

First we should do a simple way to get both integers; noting there could be multiple errors.  (Even better would be raw_input and checking the number resolves to an int).

```
integer1 = -1
integer2 = -1
while(integer1 < 1):
   integer1 = input("Enter integer 1: ")
while(integer2 < 1):
   integer2 = input("Enter integer 2: ")

factor_list1 = [] # store factor list of first number
double_factor_count = 0

# generate the factor list of the first number
for i in range(1, integer1+1): # range(1,5+1) is the list [1,2,3,4,5]
    if integer1 % i == 0:
        factor_list1.append(i)
for j in range(1, integer2+1):
    if integer2 % j == 0 and j in factor_list1:
         print j,
         double_factor_count += 1
print "\n double count:", double_factor_count
```

Possibly you want to change it to range(2, integer1) if you want to skip 1 and the integer typed in as numbers.

Note your original code wasn't indented (so didn't appear as code in the forums, and that `and` and `or` combine expressions (e.g., things that are `True` or `False`).  So you meant `if integer1 < 1 or integer2 < 1:`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually very close, but you have a few problems:

1. You're not validating `integer1` and `integer2` correctly (though I suspect you know that, since you're just printing the replacement value).
2. Your loop test is broken.  What you've written means "`i` is less than `integer1`, and also `integer2` isn't zero".

You can also improve your code in a couple of ways:

1. Ensuring that your input is not only >= 1, but also an integer.
2. Using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop, using Python's excellent iterables support.

Here's how to make sure that what the user typed was an integer:

```
integer1 = 0

while not integer1:
    try:
        # raw_input() ensures the user can't type arbitrary code
        # int() throws a ValueError if what they typed wasn't an integer
        integer1 = int(raw_input("Enter the first integer:  "))

        if integer1 < 1:
            print "You must enter an integer greater than 0!"
            integer1 = 0 # so that our while statement loops again
    except ValueError:
        # the user typed something other than an integer
        print "You must enter an integer!"
```

The `while`, `try`, and `if` statements here ensure that the user will be forced to enter a valid integer before your code continues.  Here's an example of what the user sees:

```
Enter the first integer:  6.6
You must enter an integer!
Enter the first integer:  -5
You must enter an integer greater than 0!
Enter the first integer:  sys.exit(0)
You must enter an integer!
Enter the first integer:  12
Enter the second integer:
```

And this is how I'd recommend setting up your loop:

```
# min() returns the smallest of its arguments
# xrange() iterates over a sequence of integers (here, starting with 1 and
#          stopping at min(integer1, integer2))
for i in xrange(1, min(integer1, integer2) + 1):
    # magic goes here!
```

Documentation links:

- [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html#int)
- [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html#min)
- [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html#input)
- [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/functions.html#xrange)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your if statements.

Rather than saying: `while i <= integer1 and integer2`, you need to say `while i <= integer1 and i <= integer2`

The same applies for your other if statement. `if integer1 or integer2 < 1 :` should be `if integer1 < 1 or integer2 < 1 :`